# Django selectable, AutoCompleteSelectMultiple : Form not validated

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I created a ModelForm with a widget of django-selectable:

```
class SomeRequestForm(forms.ModelForm):

created_by = selectable.AutoCompleteSelectMultipleField(lookup_class=SomeGroupUser,
    label='',
    required=True,
    widget=selectable.AutoCompleteSelectMultipleWidget)
```

My lookups:

```
class SomeGroupUser(ModelLookup):
model = User
search_fields = (
    'username__icontains',
    'first_name__icontains',
    'last_name__icontains',
)
filters = {'is_active': True,  }

def get_item_label(self, item):
    # Display for choice listings
    return u"%s, gebruikersnaam: %s" % (item.get_full_name(), item.username)
```

In my view:

```
 if request.method == "POST":
           some_request_form = SomeRequestForm(request.POST, current_user=request.user, 
            , prefix="peer", )
 else:
        some_request_form = SomeRequestForm(current_user=request.user,prefix="peer")
```

This gave the following error:

```
Cannot assign "[<User: Test Test>]": "Some.created_by" must be a "User" instance.
```

Then I tried looping the request.POST list and for each user create a form and get the user object:

```
if request.method == "POST":
        post_values = request.POST.copy()

        created_by_users = request.POST.getlist('peer-created_by_1')

        for created_by_user in created_by_users:

            created_by_user = User.objects.get(pk=5)
            post_values['peer-created_by_1'] = created_by_user

            peerassessment_form = PeerassessmentRequestForm(post_values, current_user=request.user, prefix="peer", )
```

But then I get this error:

```
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'User'
```

Then I tried to change the post values to the pk of the user and got this error:

```
Cannot assign "[<User: Test Test>]": "Some.created_by" must be a "User" instance.
```

The full traceback:

http://dpaste.com/2QT6KNK

Comment: do you have a local variable `current_user` ?

Comment: Could you post whole traceback with their error messages?

Comment: Sorry for the late response I added the traceback